# SQL CASE WHEN Statement

Tags: sql, database

I'm trying to get this statement to work but it said i have error at "INV.CaseQty = 1"

I want to get it to the logic:

```
when x = 1 then y = 1 else y

CASE WHEN INV.CaseUp = 1 then  INV.CaseQty = 1 ELSE INV.CaseQty end
```

Would greatly appreciate everyone's help

Here is my SELECT query from a stored procedure

```
select C.CustomerNum, ISNULL(ST.ShiptoNum,'') Shipto, I.InvoiceNum,
       DatePart(yyyy,I.InvoiceDate) DeliveryYear,
       DatePart(qq,I.InvoiceDate) DeliveryQuarter,
       DatePart(MM,I.InvoiceDate) DeliveryMonth,
       DatePart(WW,I.InvoiceDate) DeliveryWeek,
       CAST(I.InvoiceDate as Date) DeliveryDate, INV.InventoryNum,
       IP.InventoryPackageNum, ISNULL(CaseQty, 0) QTYinEach,
       ID.Description,ISNULL(IT.Description,'No Type') SubCategory,
       CASE WHEN INV.CaseUp = 1 then  INV.CaseQty = 1
            ELSE INV.CaseQty
       end
```

original table

```
Description                             CaseQty     caseup
Royal 5" Red Stripe Plastic Sip Stirrer 1000          1
Ecoproducts Plant Starch Knife          1000          0
Ecoproducts Plant Starch Fork           1000          1
Ecoproducts Plant Starch Spoon          1000          0
```

I want the select query from my store procedure to be able to change those with CaseUp = 1, CaseQty should be change to 1 as well.

Comment: what you want to achieve is it a select statement? Post the complete query for appropriate answers

Comment: yes i want to use it in a select statement so if i was to perform an IF statement i can't put it in a select statement. I only could use CASE it seems like. How do i work around this?

Comment: post your select query to show what you want to achieve or atleast table data and result data after query to understand your requirement

Comment: Why do you have to assign a value in a table column? Are you trying to UPDATE the table row with that value on that column? If not, you can use a variable to hold that value into instead.

Comment: If it is a store procedure then it is PL-SQL In Pl-SQL you can write any number of separate statements and expressions. why to club them all in one.

Comment: No FROM clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot "set a value" as your attempting to do with `INV.CaseQty = 1`, you are SELECTING values from a table

```
SELECT CASE WHEN INV.CaseUp = 1 THEN 1 ELSE INV.CaseQty END as CaseQty
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic that you describe is incoherent: in the THEN clause you are performing an operation but in the ELSE clause you are returning a value, and those actions are incompatible.

The assignment process would be done via the IF...ELSE structure; returning different values based on conditions would be done via the CASE structure.

Comment: but OP didn't mention of using PLSQL

Comment: Neither did I ;)

Comment: how can you use if else in sql query(I don't know this possible).

Comment: Take a look at what Hans posted (below).

However, that will fail because the ELSE clause does not contain a complete statement.  We're hampered here because we don't know what the OP is trying to accomplish.

Comment: Is it in select query ?

Comment: The OP just posted an update - this is from a select statement.  So the attempt to assign a value in the middle of a select won't work, as has been stated.

Answer (score 0):

it kind of looks like you need it for where clause
maybe like :

```
where 
((INV.CaseUp = 1 and INV.CaseQty = 1) or INV.CaseUp <> 1)
```